# How to use loops in Facelets

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

I have a method in Bean Class which returns `ArrayList<String>`
i.e `PlacesList[Akividu, House, Shopping Store, Sri Malleswara and Venkateswara Temple, Bus Station, Gangaratnam Theatre, Mohan Studio, HP Petrol Bunk, Primary School, Madiwada School, Library, Vegetable Market, Akividu Police Station]`.

I would like to display all these in one by one.
If I use the below line of code

```
<h:outputText value="#{searchBean.searchResults()[0]}" />
```

I am getting the single value only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [**`<ui:repeat>`**](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/facelets/10-TagReference/facelets-ui-repeat.html) tag to iterate over a collection.
Below is a sample example:

XHTML:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{productController.products}" var="product">
            <li><h:outputText value="#{product.name}" /></li>
        </ui:repeat>
```

ManagedBean:

```
private List<Product> products;

public List<Product> getProducts() {
    if (products == null) {
        products = new ArrayList<Product>();
        products.add(new Product("Tennis Racket"));
        products.add(new Product("Baseball Bat"));
        products.add(new Product("Hockey Stick"));
    }
    return products;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use JSTL's [**`<c:forEach>`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) Tag.

Comment: raj, how exactly is this exception message unclear? You seemed to have feeded the `<ui:repeat>` a `List<String>` instead of `List<Product>` without changing the `#{product.name}` to `#{product}` in the view. It makes completely sense that you would get this exception then. The `String` class doesn't have a `name` property at all.

Comment: Thanks alot BalusC ,GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR